# There is no bijection between $I_n$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
$
Let $I_n = \{i \in \N~|~i \le n\}$. The claim probably seems trivial to most of you, but I tested myself whether I can prove it.

It is sufficient to show that for every $n \in \N$, there is no surjection from $I_n $ onto $\N$.

I tried proof by induction.

1. **base step**:
   Let $I_1 \to \N$ be the set of all functions from $I_1$ to $\N$. Then,
   $$
   I_1 \to \N = \{\{(1,n)\}~|~ n \in \N\}
   $$
   Let $f \in I_1 \to \N$ be arbitrary. There is $n \in \N$ such that $f =\{(1,n)\}$. $f(1) = n$ is the only element in $f[I_1]$, but $n + 1 \in \N$, which means $f$ is not surjective.
2. **inductive step**:
   Let $n \in \N$, and assume there is no surjection in $I_n \to \N$. Let $f \in I_{n+1} \to \N$ be arbitrary. Aiming for contradiction, let $f$ is a surjection. Then, $g = f \setminus \{(n+1, f(n+1))\}$ is a surjection in $I_n \to \N \setminus \{f(n+1)\}$. We can define a function $h \in I_n \to \N$ such that
   $$
   h(i)
   =
   \begin{cases}
   g(i), & g(i) < f(n+1)\\
   g(i) - 1, & g(i) \ge f(n+1)
   \end{cases}
   $$
   for all $i \in I_n$. Then, $h$ is a surjection, which contradicts the inductive hypothesis.

**Questions:**

1. Is this a valid proof?
2. Is there a simpler proof?

Comment: A simpler proof: There is no surjection $I_n\to I_{n+1}$ by the pigeonhole principle. $I_{n+1}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, so there is no surjection $I_n\to\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you but it makes me want to prove the pigeonhole principle... :)

Comment: Or prove by induction that the image of every $f:I_n\to\mathbb N$ has a maximal element.

Comment: Your proof has a problem when $f(n+1)=1$ and $f(i)=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof has a problem when $f(n+1)=1$ and some other $f(i)=1.$ Then $h(i)=0.$

**Aside** I am assuming $0\not\in\mathbb N,$ since you started your induction on $I_1.$ If $0\in\mathbb N,$ then the problem occurs when $f(n+1)=0.$

You can work around that with a special case when $h(n+1)=1.$

It more direct proof is to prove by induction:

> **Lemma:** If $f:I_n\to\mathbb N,$ then there is an $M\in \mathbb N$ such that $f(i)\leq M$ for all $i\in\mathbb N.$

After showing this, given any $f,$ find $M,$ and then $f(i)=M+1$ has no solution.

**Outline of induction step of lemma:** Given $f:I_{n+1}\to \mathbb N,$ let $g=f_{|I_n}.$ Then there is an $M_1$ such that $g(i)\leq M_1$ for all $i\in I_n.$ Let $M=\max(M_1,f(n+1)).$

Comment: OP could also avoid this problem by proving directly that there is no bijection rather than proving that there is no surjection.  Then $ f ( n + 1 ) = f ( i ) $ would be impossible for $ i < n $.  (Admittedly, OP would have to do more work, proving that $ h $ is an injection before getting a contradiction.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Yeah. it is easy to go from "No surjection to $I_{n+1}$" to "No surjection to $\mathbb N.$" It is harder to go from "No bijection to $I_{n+1}$" to "No bijection to $\mathbb N.$" For example, there is no bijection $\mathbb N\to\mathbb I_{n+1},$ but there is a bijection $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N,$ obviously.

Comment: Andrews, I was already aware of your lemma, but fail to invoke it when proving the claim. Your answer is so satisfying. I decide to abandon my approach because it's too complex than necessary. Thank you! I admit I love MSE except for the new UI.